# Storing dig output in array

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match, dig

I have this MX output in `$ip`:

```
10 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM. 10 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM. 1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM. 5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM. 5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
```

The number is the priority and the subdomain is the mail server. How could I stored them in array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
        )
...
)
```

The hard part is the whole output could be anything. I mean the mail server subdomain name and the number of server could be random. In the above is 5 mail server but it could be 3 or just 1 server (not to be confuse with mail server priority number).

I'm thinking about `preg_match`, but the random subdomain name just leaves me clueless.  Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr = array();

preg_match_all('/(\d+) ([\w.\-]+)/', $ip, $matches);
for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++)
{
    $arr[] = array($matches[1][$i], $matches[2][$i]);
}
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
        )

)
```

Comment: I add `0 see-why.net.` in `$ip` and the array output is: `[1] => see` As you can see the `-why.net.` is missing. Help me with the `-` problem please?

Comment: @sg552:  I've updated my answer.  You just needed to add `-` to the character class.